# iOS : How using different size image with the same name in Assets.xcassets when Running on different device or different landscape

Tags: ios, xcode

### Purpose

I am to make my iOS app run on the different device include iPhone and iPad.
I want to setup the ImageView's image with different size using the same name for Adapting to the different devices and landscape.

### What I am doing

#### 1.import image into Assets.xcassets for different device traits.

> apple program reference: [Create asset variations for different device traits](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev89659e6a1)

The image inside xcodes' Assets.xcassets has different width or height class setting. I name the image after "homeBackground"

The image like this :

> [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXHk4.png

### 2. drag the imageView into Interface Builder

### 3. set the imageView's attributes: Image  in the Interface Builder as the image's name "homeBackground"

### 4. view as iPad or iPhone

using xcode 8.3. I can preview the scene. 
I can see the imageView's image is set successfully, When viewing as Ipad or iPhone

### Problem

run the app in xcode. I don't see the imageView has the image in the simulator and I have the following question:

> Could not load the "homeBackground" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "BTBubblePop"

### complete

1. I run it in the iPad, the ImageView's image shows
2. I run it in the iPhone, the ImageView's image don't show.

Comment: Can you please explain the question in detail. What do you mean by How to set image view in Xcode interface builder?

Comment: thanks for your comment. I have completed the question. Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: What is this identifier BTBubblePop?

Comment: Generic solution: first try to debug imageview coming or not by setting different background color for imageview. Once you confirm that imageview coming but problem with image then that means something wrong with image and deal with it.

Comment: BTBubblePop is my Buddle identifier.

Comment: Can you please remove that imageview and drag and place it again and set image

Comment: I have setting the color. The imageView comes.

Comment: Looks strange. You are doing it correct

Comment: Thanks.  I find the answer. It's the image set not correctly. should change like below.

Comment: thanks again. @Sivajee Battina

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your focus and comment.
the question is called by the image not set correctly. 
The image's assets.xcassets change like this. That's worked.
The Image should like these.

> [Image should set like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5rDx.png)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly the answer is that it goes by image set name.

[image]

Or in code

```
UIImage *image =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"homeBackground"];
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: I set name like your first choice. But I still have the error like the qustion description.